# Two close methods in try-with-resources

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

I've got the following code:

```
try(Socket s1=new Socket(...); Socket s2=new Socket(...);)
{
  some logic...
}
```

As I understood, Java closes `s2` first and then`s1`.
What will happen, if `s2.close()` throws exception? Will Java try to close `s1` after previous failure?

Comment: Yes. try-with-resources guarantees `close` will be called on both `s2` and `s1` (in that order).

Comment: Is this behaviour documented somewhere? Because I can not find it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [JLS Sec 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) (emphasis mine):

> Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value. **An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources.**